# Parse a HTML page to extract the fields into an array like : value=>option_text

Tags: php, parsing, xpath, domdocument

Current scenario :

I'm loading a html page into a var with DomDocument

```
$dom    = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');  
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

and I need to parse 3 lists of option fields . The HTML looks like this :

```
<li>
    <select id="advertiser" name="advertiser[]" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off">                                                                         <option value="35" >Website Adv 1</option>
    <option value="36" >Website Adv 1</option>                                                                                                          <option value="41" >Website Adv 1</option>
    <option value="45" >Website Adv 1</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Now I found this code on Stack but it does not work ..

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='advertiser[]']/option");
foreach ($options as $option) {
  $optionValue = $option->getAttribute('value');
  $optionContent = $option->nodeValue;
  echo "$optionValue and $optionContent\n";
}
```

The question remains :

How do I parse a HTML page to extract the fields of an option select, into an array like : value=>option_text

Comment: I would think you'd want `//select[@name...` instead of `*/select`

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should work. You can change the code by this

```
$dom    = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');  
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$options = $xpath->query("*/select[@name='advertiser[]']/option");
$result = array();
foreach ($options as $option) {
  $optionValue = $option->getAttribute('value');
  $optionContent = $option->nodeValue;
  $result[$optionValue] = $optionContent;
}

print_r($result);
```

to load into $result array the items like you want to.

The result should be:

```
Array
(
    [35] => Website Adv 1
    [36] => Website Adv 1
    [41] => Website Adv 1
    [45] => Website Adv 1
)
```

Comment: thank you . I think there is an invisible error around ... yes, this works great .. I think maybe the html page is malformed or something .. the $html is the result / return of a cURL ... i don't get it ..

the html is there, the results are empty ..

Comment: As php page says (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) the loadHtml function returns a boolean to check if it´s a valid HTML string. You can check it.

Comment: So if there is anything else before the select input, any kind of data, like other tags or text .. the Xpath does not work ...

Comment: Can this be done in some other way ? how do I parse the code by nodes ?